# In Laravel my terminal php artisan give error Call to a member function connection() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Laravel 5.8.0

I have projekt in Laravel. There is many problems with it, first with run it on Virtual host. When I was trying to resolve it, I run it by by command php artisan serve. Unfortunately I discovered that every command php artisan give me back the same errors:

```
In Model.php line 1058:

  Call to a member function connection() on null
```

In this line in Model.php I have:

```
   * @param  string|null  $connection
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Connection
     */
    public static function resolveConnection($connection = null)
    {
        return static::$resolver->connection($connection);
    }
```

I don't know exactly what's wrong and why this $connection is null.

Edit:

I add below my database.php and .env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:2OWwGrH6hL+4MKkV7sZZ21MTjSHv/zacUDC67FWVBa4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=32252630
DB_USERNAME=32252630
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=cms_

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=serwer2020202.home.pl
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mail@mail.pl
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=kontakt1@mailpl
MAIL_FROM_NAME=kontakt1@mail.pl

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=

CMS_INSTALLED=true
```

```
return [
'default' => (!empty(env('DB_CONNECTION'))) ? env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql') : 'sqlite',

'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'admin'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => env('DB_TABLE_PREFIX', ''),
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

    ],
'migrations' => 'migrations',

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Edit:

About the Model.php and the $resolver inside there is the code:

```
use Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolverInterface as Resolver;
    * @var \Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolverInterface
     */
    protected static $resolver;
```

I've done some research with this problems, and do something with my problem. After trying some advices I gone to this place, where I have new error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\jjk\laravel_core\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:788
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\jjk\laravel_core\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(788): ReflectionClass->__construct('config')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\jjk\laravel_core\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('config')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\jjk\laravel_core\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(615): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('config', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\jjk\laravel_core\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(767): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('config', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\jjk\laravel_core\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1227): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('config')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\jjk\laravel_core\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Il in C:\xampp\htdocs\jjk\laravel_core\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 788
```

I tried to search the solution, but nothing was helpful. Anyone have some idea?

Comment: There might be an error with your configurations. Will you please post `config/database.php` file and `.env` file in your question?

Comment: ```static::$resolver``` is null, that is the core laravel class right, Model.php? what is your laravel version?

Comment: Yes, Model.php is Class in my laravel_core/vendor/laravel/framework/Illumiante/Database/Eloquent/Model.php. I will add to my question the $resolver code in Model.php. And I have laravel in version 5.4.*

Comment: I was update my laravel today to 5.8 but it didn't help.